# Cannot instantiate class with TestNG Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testng

When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
Cannot instantiate class mypackage.GoogleSearch
```

How can it be fixed?

Code:

```
package mypackage;

import org.testng.annotations.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class GoogleSearch {
    public String url = "http://www.google.com/";
    public WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

  @Test
  public void search() {      
      driver.get(url);          
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working, apparently I needed to install the stand-alone server: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar&can=1&q= If anyone could explain why it'd be great, with Visual Studio I just had to install selenium client