# org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot instantiate class TestNG.DemoTestNG

Tags: java, selenium

Here is my problem.
 After executing testNG script , I'm getting error stating 
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class TestNG.DemoTestNG. Can anybody please give me the solution for my problem.

```
public class DemoTestNG {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        String appUrl = "http://192.168.1.116:9090/soxaudit/login";
       @Test
        public void Sox_Login() {
            driver.get(appUrl);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        String expectedTitle = "SOX ADMIN - LOGIN";

                String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
                Assert.assertEquals(expectedTitle,actualTitle);
        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("j_username"));
        username.clear();
        username.sendKeys(new String[]{"sox"});
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("j_password"));
        password.clear();
        password.sendKeys(new String[]{"welcome@123"});      
        WebElement SignInButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login-page']/div/form/div/button"));
        SignInButton.click();               
// close the web browser
        driver.close();
        System.out.println("Test script executed successfully.");

// terminate the program
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked fine for me. From where are you starting the tests? Do you have selenium standalone server in reference library ( if using eclipse).

Comment: I am starting the test in WebDriver.

Comment: May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860587/cannot-instantiate-class-with-testng-selenium) solution can help.

Comment: i have TestNG with eclipse, can i install selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar. Wont it affect the working set up?

Comment: Ofcourse use the latest version..39 could be latest at time of the question asked

Comment: are you running tests from TestNG.xml file? If yes,  please post that